# Regex for Windows path strings

Tags: javascript, regex, windows

I am trying to use a reg ex which validates `Windows path string`. I am using the following reg ex

```
[\w]:\.* .
```

The following egs should be validated.

```
Abc.txt
HelloWorld\Abc.txt
..\Hello\World\Abc.txt
C:\Program Files\TaaSera\LiveTrust\Abc.txt
```

At present C:// is only getting validated. Please help.

Comment: `:` is metacharacter, it has to be escaped

Comment: @hindmost : do you mean something like this [\w]\.*

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=345 (there is alot more on that site)

Comment: @hindmost: Are you sure. While `:` forms part of various syntaxes (eg. not capturing groupd) it isn't a meta-character in its own right.

Comment: Also, do you want all file extension's to be valid or do you only want `.txt` to be valid? Should network drives `\\\` be valid?

Comment: You seem to be looking for paths of the form "x:\name\…\name.ext`. However there are also `\\computer\share\…\name` and `\\?\D:\very long path` to bypass the normal file length limits. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this regex:

```
^[\w\\.:\s]+?\.\w{2,4}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jM1sQ0/2)

Comment: Abc.txt in this Abc$& is also getting accepted. I guess these special characters are not allowed in windows file name

Comment: @user2998990 ok, what about `^[\w\\.:\s]+?\.\w{2,4}`?

Comment: Windows "normal" paths are driver letter, colon, backslash, and then names separated by backslashes.

Comment: @m.cekiera : seems ok... Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: @m.cekiera : C:// is not getting validated.

Comment: @user2998990 this regex works with input you provided, and in your examples, every "path" ends with extension `.xyz`, so it works only for string with extensions. It would be de best to post all form of path you want to validate, without it it will be always missing something